# Spring Cloud Stream unit test Producer

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream 3.1.3.
I'm migrate from a pre 3.1 version, so I wrote my producer using a java.util.Function (I know I can use Supplier but this is what I need)

`application.yaml` file is configured with function definition, input and output bindings, and this is what I have:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Service
public class Producer {
    public void produce(int messageId, Object data) {
        Message<Object> message = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(data)
                .setHeader(PARTITION_KEY, messageId)
                .build();
        
        streamBridge.send("produceMessage-in-0", message);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<Message<Object>, Message<Object>> produceMessage() {
        return (input) -> {
            int messageId = input.getHeaders().get(PARTITION_KEY, Integer.class);
            Object message = input.getPayload();
    
            return MessageBuilder
                            .withPayload(message)
                            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .setHeader(PARTITION_KEY, messageId)
                            .setHeader("type", "MyMessage")
                            .build();
        };
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to test this implmentation, so I wrote this test class

```
@SpringBootTest
class ProducerTest {
    @Autowired
    private Producer producer;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    void produceOk() {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.getCompleteConfiguration(Producer.class)).run()) {
            producer.produce(1, new MyMessage(1, "Hello"));
            
            OutputDestination output = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);
            Message<byte[]> received = output.receive();

            Assertions.assertNotNull(received);
       }
    }
}
```

Test fails because output.receive() returns null.

Is this the right way to test my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see what your issue may be since we don't see the entire setup of your project, but here are few pointers that may help. . .

Please look at any of the [tests we use in the framework](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/tree/main/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function) as well as checkout the [Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing) section of the reference manual.

There is also s dedicated [StreamBridgeTests.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamBridgeTests.java) which is what I believe you are looking for.